# How to get dictionary values from Outside the dictionary/ or class

Tags: c#, class, object, dictionary

Say I have a dictionary function in 1 class:

```
public static class Class1
{
    public static void StatDict(int EventNumber, string EventCode)
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> Dict1 = new Dictionary<int, sting>();

        Dictionary.Add(EventNumber, EventCode);
    }
}
```

Example of input: EventNumber = '4', EventCode = '4TUI'// This is fed from another class, Class2

And I want to get compare say, Int i = 4, in class 2 or function to key 4 of the Dictionary, so that I can pull out the value for key 4. (ie '4TUI').

```
public static class Class2
{
    public void CompareIntToDictionary()
    {
        Int Compare= 4;

        if (Compare == Dictionary(value);????????????????????? // *This part i need help with*
        {
            Do something!!!
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone able to tell me how I can reference a dictionary that exists in 1 class in order to pull out the value associated with the key, if it matches say an Integer I define elsewhere (ie in another class)? Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: Thanks for this, seems it does seem to do the trick, with the exception the following bit of code does returns false, even though I know the key is there, it skips this (therefore false):

```
int Compare = 4;
if (Class1.Dict1.ContainsKey(Compare))
{
    var eventCodecheck = Class1.Dict1[Compare];
    Debug.WriteLine("eventcode = " + eventCodecheck);
    // Do something!!!
}
```

but now I face the problem that I need to override GetHashCode and Equals in order to do compare the keys from 2 different objects using dictionary.

This is the code i was using thanks to the helpful answer, but I'm not quite sure how to override GetHascode and Equals with regards this:

```
    public static class Class1
    {
        public static Dictionary<int, string> Dict1 { get; set; }
        public static void StatDict(int EventNumber, string EventCode)
        {
            Dict1 = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            Dict1.Add(EventNumber, EventCode);
            Debug.WriteLine("EventNumber = " + EventNumber + " EventCode = " +       EventCode);
    }

}

public static class Class2
{
    public static void CompareIntToDictionary()
    { 
        int Compare = 4;
        if (Class1.Dict1.ContainsKey(Compare))
        {
            var eventCodecheck = Class1.Dict1[Compare];
            Debug.WriteLine("eventcode = " + eventCodecheck);

            // Do something!!!
        }
    }
}
```

I'm just learning this stuff.

Comment: So what's your question? Does your `CompareIntToDictionary` method not work?

Comment: Basically, yes it skips past this check even though I Know that there is a key of '4' and a assosiated value.  So, it looks like int compare = 4; is not the same as the key in Dict1 for 4. It seems not all Int's created equally hence hashcode....

Comment: `int` returns its value as hash code, so you don't need to override `GetHashCode` method (and you can't actually do this for `int`). Are you sure you call `StatDict` method first, then `CompareIntToDictionary`? Also, each time you call `StatDict`, it creates a new empty dictionary. You need to move `Dict1 = new Dictionary<int, string>();` to another method and call it once before others, to be sure the dictionary is created only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expose the dictionary you created in `Class1` and use it in the `Class2`:

```
public static class Class1
{
    public static Dictionary<int, string> Dict1 { get; set; }

    public static void StatDict(int EventNumber, string EventCode)
    {
        Dict1 = new Dictionary<int, sting>();

        Dict1.Add(EventNumber, EventCode);
    }
}

public static class Class2
{
    public void CompareIntToDictionary()
    {
        int Compare = 4;

        if (Class1.Dict1.ContainsKey(Compare))
        {
            var eventCode = Class1.Dict1[Compare];
            // Do something!!!
        }
    }
}
```

And better use objects instead of statics.

Comment: "boy" is a bit disrespectful

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input guys, and you can call me whatever you want if you can help me!

In the end I switched to sorted lists which fixed the issue, but the code posted helped point me in the right direction so thanks a lot.